# Error when trying to print variable in Xcode 9.4

Tags: xcode, lldb

I'm on Xcode 9.4 (9F1027a). I'm trying to do this:

```
(lldb) po bar
error: Couldn't apply expression side effects : couldn't get the data for variable self
```

At the same time, this works:

```
(lldb) fr v bar
(String?) bar = nil
```

This happens regardless of the variable type, be it local or global. Ideas?

Edit:
The problem seems to be resolved with one of the Xcode updates since then (currently 12.1 is the latest), however I since then encountered a similar issue caused by something else, maybe it will help some people arriving here from google search. So make sure you have `All Output` selected in the selection box at the bottom of the debugger window.
[image]

Comment: Having the same problem. Don't know why. Thanks for the `fr v bar` line, though, so I can at least see what's there... Have you recently added any launch arguments or environment variables to your scheme?

Comment: @leanne No, I can't recall adding anything unusual.

Comment: In my case, I'd added `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` as a launch argument. My app failed with an `EXC_...` exception, suggesting something was nil; however, it gave no indication of what. Without the launch argument, the app didn't fail, so I wasn't sure what was nil. With the argument, when it failed, none of my variables appeared to be nil in Xcode's variables list, and `po` was giving me the subject message. Using `fr v`, I was able to see something that was nil. A bug in Xcode/lldb, perhaps?

Comment: No idea what the cause of the problem is, but `po print(whatever)` seems to be a good workaround.